# What is the way to approach having an array of categorical features as input into a machine learning model?

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, tensorflow, categorical-data

Say I have an array for every training example in my training data set and this array has a varying size, containing one word tags/categories that describe the specific example. Some examples of the values in this array for different training examples would be:

```
["cat", "animal", "meow", "dark]
["stationary", "pen", "drawing"]
```

In tensorflow what would be the approach to handling these arrays of categories that have varying size for each input to make them features of the model? I just can't figure out how to do this and can't figure out if I am over thinking it. Could I one hot encode each entry of each array so that each array would turn into an array of arrays, which could all have varying lengths? Is there a better approach than this? I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while and can't make much progress.

Comment: I don't know tensorflow, but maybe there is a simple example of what you are trying to do in the documentation.

Comment: i have looked quite a bit and have been unable to find anything quite like my issue in their documentation

Comment: one hot encoding approach is good. With that you will have sparse matrix but nonetheless it can accommodate varying array length problem. Don't be stuck, proceed, train a model and see results.